# why i have to click twice to make input change react native muliple select

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-native

When I trying to select input , I have to select item twice.

How can I make it select from the first time when I choose.

I use `useEffect()` to render `useEffect(() => {},[item1])`

```
<MultiSelect
  items={items}
  uniqueKey={items.index}
  onSelectedItemsChange={(text) => {
    setItemSelected(text);
    console.log(itemSelected[0]);
    items.map((item, index) => {
      if (item._id === itemSelected[0]) {
        setItem1(item);
      }
    });
  }}
  selectedItems={itemsSearch}
  searchInputPlaceholderText="Search Items..."
  onChangeInput={(text) => {
    setItemSearch(text);
    setItemsSearch(text);
    console.log(itemsSearch);
  }}
  selectText={item1.name}
  textColor="#6E7C95"
  tagRemoveIconColor="#353C49"
  tagBorderColor="#353C49"
  tagTextColor="#353C49"
  selectedItemTextColor="#353C49"
  selectedItemIconColor="#353C49"
  itemTextColor="#000"
  displayKey="name"
  searchInputStyle={{ color: "#353C49" }}
  single
  //styleDropdownMenu={styles.inputSearchStyle}
  styleDropdownMenuSubsection={styles.inputSearchStyle}
  hideSubmitButton
/>;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by changing method  onSelectedItemsChange
to

```
 onSelectedItemsChange={(itemSelected) => {
                setItemSelected(itemSelected);
                console.log(itemSelected);
                items.map((item, index) => {
                  if (item._id === itemSelected[0]) {
                    setItem1(item);
                  }
```

```
            });
          }}
```